# How to hide Tool bar and TabLayout when I scroll ListView in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I am very new in android , when I scroll my list how to hide tool bar and Tab Layout, I place TextView in between tool Bar and Tab Layout ,when I scroll my listview I want to hide my tool bar and tab layout , text view,please any one help me how to do this ,thank you in advance 
here my XML code

XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"   android:background="@drawable/imag_bg" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="AppName"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use coordinateLayout and AppbarLayout to do this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tabUnselectedColor"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

also you have to add the layout_behavior to the viewPager and  scrollFlag to AppBarLayout

Comment: is it possible without using coordinate layout@Tabish Hussain

Comment: then you might have to animate it using Animation

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Application Title"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabTextColor="#fff" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```